# How to filter the list views and displayed in the layout?

Tags: java, android, android-listview

In my Grouchat tab, I have both event and invitation listviewes(first listview denotes "event" and second listview denotes "invitation"). Now i am need to filter my listviewes using dropdown items(it displayed in imaged-2).when i am ontap event item i need to display only the event items similarly ontap invitation item from the dropdown i need to display invitation items on layout.When ontap item All i need to display both event and invitation items.How to achieve that please suggest me the code.

[image]

[image]

I am tried following code for filter the event listviewes,

```
public void displayEventList() {
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        sharedpreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(Constants.SHARED_PREFERENCE_NAME,
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        DatabaseHelper dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
        final UserMO userMO = dbHelper.getRingeeUserData(1);
        new AsyncTask<Void, Void, List<EventMO>>() {
            @Override
            protected List<EventMO> doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                eventMOs = gson.fromJson(eventDelegates.getAllEventFromUser(userMO, context), new TypeToken<List<EventMO>>() {
                }.getType());
                List<EventMO> groupEventList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (EventMO eventMO : eventMOs) {
                    groupEventList.add(eventMO);

                }
                return groupEventList;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(List<EventMO> groupEventList) {
                groupEventMoList = groupEventList;
                chatDisplayAdapter = new ChatDisplayAdapter();
                groupEventView.setAdapter(chatDisplayAdapter);
                groupEventView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                groupEventView.setItemsCanFocus(true);
                groupEventView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
                groupEventView.setOnItemClickListener(groupEventView.getOnItemClickListener());
            }

        }.execute(null, null, null);
    }
```